# Can jQuery.getScript show the file as a resource in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code needs to load scripts on demand.

```
function includeJS(uri) {
    return jQuery.getScript(uri);
}

includeJS('/path/to/script.js').always(function() {
    // do something after script is loaded
});
```

The problem, though, is that the JS file will not be available in the Chrome Developer tools like other files that were included statically on the page. Due to this I cannot easily put break points.

Is there an alternative to jQuery.getScript that will also show the script in the Chrome Developer tools with the ability to put break points?

---

EDIT: Adding solution based on currently accepted answer (I will still consider other solutions, but this seems to work for me)

```
function includeJS(uri) {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = uri;
    script.onload = function() {
        def.resolve();
    }
    script.onerror = function() {
        def.reject();
    }
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return def.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply append a `script` tag, and use an `onload` handler to execute post-load actions. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0nu2dusu/

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'my_external_script.js';
script.onload = loadHandler;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

You have slightly less control over failed loads than `$.getScript` offers, but the script does show up in dev tools.

Comment: I think this is the solution I will use, at first I tried using jQuery('<script src="...">') but I think jQuery is doing some magic behind the scenes - manually doing document.createElement() worked.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's always there. Just take a look at an example from the [jQuery.getScript() site](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/). Here's how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcFqX.png.
The problem with `.getScript()` is that it never caches files requested, so on every call it adds some random string to prevent caching (what also prevents us from debugging code). But there's workaround for that:

1. Set global `.ajax` caching (not recommended) before you call `.getScript()`:

   ```
   $.ajaxSetup({
     cache: true
   });
   ```
2. Use direct `.ajax()` call (recommended):

   ```
   $.ajax({
       dataType: "script",
       cache: true,
       url: url
   }
   ```
3. If it's your own script, you can always add a `debugger;` command anywhere to force browser to enter the debug mode (DevTools must be opened).

Comment: I don't know if it is a problem with just my version of jQuery.getScript or Chrome - but it does not appear to ever show the script in the "Sources" tab of Chrome - however, I did notice that when setting cache:true as suggested, the HTTP request no longer contains the params and caches the response properly. Putting "debugger" is what I've been doing, however, Chrome always would show the script as "VM" scripts similar to scripts executed using "eval"

Comment: I just tried this google chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit), and it does not work