# Why I can't see .js files in Sources tab in google chrome developer tools when I use jquery method $.getScript()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I can see every js file in Sources tab in google chrome developer tools when I use  tag in html file to include js file, but when I use jquery method  $.getScript() to load js file, I cann't see it in Sources tab in google chrome developer tools anymore, why? I have searched other similar questions in stackoverflow, but none of them give a clear answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057153/can-jquery-getscript-show-the-file-as-a-resource-in-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: The answers of it tells how to show , but I want to know why it cann't show, I think it is something concerns about the mechanism of jquery or google chrome.